# What do you call the metal corners on a briefcase?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some suitcases and briefcases have metal reinforcements at the corner, sometimes in gold, sometimes in silver. Is there a specific word in English for those or should I simply say "....with golden metal reinforcements at the corner..."?

[image: vintage Luis Vuitton case with brass corners]

Comment: Could you please capitalize the word *English* in your question title? If you want to write on an English forum, make the best effort to use good English.

Comment: The metal corners, the most common term, are either in brass, nickel or nickel-plated.

Comment: Thank you Mari-Lou. 
This forum, however, seems to have a unwelcoming and inhospitible atmosphere. I am looking for another place to learn.
Bye.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a specific word for this. Looking at products, I'm seeing:

- [**Reinforced Metal Corners**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074XDFR1M)
- [Features a flat finish and **black corner reinforcements**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ICNR78)
- [Black briefcase with **brass corner protectors**](http://bid.whitleyauction.com/lot/48050-35872-54300/black-briefcase-with-brass-corner-protectors---4-5/)
- [Vintage Oak Wood & Leather Briefcase **Brass Corner Guards** Wooden Handle](http://www.ebay.com.sg/itm/Vintage-Oak-Wood-amp-Leather-Briefcase-Brass-Corner-Guards-Wooden-Handle-/181578210614)
- [Vtg Lito Leather **Brass Corner** Briefcase Varese Italy OCS Combination Lock](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/262177797848)

You could use any of these and be understood.

Comment: [Corner guard](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/corner+guard) seems to have at least one dictionary entry.

Comment: These can also be small *[Trunk Corner Caps](http://www.furnitureknowledge.com/Trunk-Corner-Caps-c6108769)* or *[Trunk Corner Guards](http://www.archiviemiliogreco.com/MTUzM-trunk-corner-guards.html).*